# Python синтаксис

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Какие варианты Вы знаете сравнения 2х списков, например [0, 1, 2, 3] и [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

Элегантно было бы писать так:

```
for el1, el2 in list1, list2:
        if not el1 == el2:
            return False
return True
```

Или если бы была какая-нибудь такая конструкция:

```
(list1 in list2) && (list2 in list1)
```

Но такие операции непозволительны в питоне. Как можно выйти из ситуации не используя итерационный for loop `(for i in range(len(list)): ...)`

Comment: хммм, а разве обычное == не работает?

Comment: А чем не устроило `if list1 == list2`?

Comment: про zip слышали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
list1 == list2
```

списки сравниваются поэлементно до первого несовпадения, либо пока в одном из них не закончатся элементы.

Comment: Да, мне нужно повторить матчасть)

Answer (score 1):

Это даст пересечение обоих списков:

```
result=list(set(Ans) & set(Word))

['red', 'white']
```

Если нужен список уникальных элементов в объединении двух списков:

```
['red', 'white', 'green', 'blue']

result = list(set(Ans + Word))
```

Симметричная разность:

```
['green','blue']

result=list(set(Ans) ^ set(Word))
```

Обычная разность(Множество из Ans не входящее в Word):

```
['green','blue']

result=list(set(Ans) - set(Word))
```

Comment: Будет ожидаемо работать только если списки не содержат одинаковых значений.